# Jquery sorting array of numbers and strings alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects with numbers and strings. The sorting with number columns works fine, but the one with strings seems to have some issues. I can't figure out the problem here....

```js
result = [{
      "title": "test",
      "client": "test",
      "price": 5000,
      "calories": 10,
      "eggless": "false",
      "date": "2017-09-09"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon Sugar Fried Apples",
      "client": "Frodo Baggins",
      "price": 1100,
      "calories": 1997.07,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-06"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon, Apple, Oatmeal Cake",
      "client": "Bruce Banner",
      "price": 390,
      "calories": 2007.07,
      "eggless": false,
      "date": "2017-07-09"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon, Apple, Oatmeal Cake",
      "client": "Bruce Banner",
      "price": 390,
      "calories": 2007.07,
      "eggless": false,
      "date": "2017-07-09"
    }, {
      "title": "Chocolate Pancakes With Fruits",
      "client": "Bilbo Baggins",
      "price": 300,
      "calories": 1997.07,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-04"
    }, {
      "title": "Chocolate Pancakes With Fruits",
      "client": "Bilbo Baggins",
      "price": 300,
      "calories": 1997.07,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-04"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon-Apple Bread",
      "client": "Tony Stark",
      "price": 250,
      "calories": 1500,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-08"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon-Apple Bread",
      "client": "Tony Stark",
      "price": 250,
      "calories": 1500,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-08"
    }, {
      "title": "Pecan Tart",
      "client": "Scrats Squirrel",
      "price": 210,
      "calories": 1999,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-08"
    }, {
      "title": "Pecan Tart",
      "client": "Scrats Squirrel",
      "price": 210,
      "calories": 1999,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-08"
    }, {
      "title": "Cinnamon Sugar Fried Apples",
      "client": "Frodo Baggins",
      "price": 200,
      "calories": 1997.07,
      "eggless": true,
      "date": "2017-07-06"
    }];
    
    let column = "title";
    let sortOrder = "sort-asc";
    if ($.isNumeric(result[0][column])) {
      result.sort(function(first, second) {
        if (sortOrder === "sort-asc") return first[column] - second[column];
        else if (sortOrder === "sort-desc") return second[column] - first[column]; //first[column] < second[column];
      });
    } else {
      if (sortOrder === "sort-asc") result.sort();
      else if (sortOrder === "sort-desc") result.sort().reverse();
    }
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What **jQuery** has to do with it..? you can use `lodash` library for that (see [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy) method)

Comment: That was because I am implementing this in a script with jquery. Javascript is fine too

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.localeCompare`

```
else {
    result.sort(function (first, second) {
        if (sortOrder === "sort-asc") return first[column].localeCompare(second[column]);
        else if (sortOrder === "sort-desc") return second[column].localeCompare(first[column]); //first[column] < second[column];
    });
}
console.log(result);
```